# Where to store confidential / private media files (images, videos) in Yii2?

Tags: php, server, yii2, filesystems

I am building a web application that is familiar to Facebook in structure, in that that each user logs in into their own little domain, and should only be able to access their own images, videos, sound files. Is it alright to store these files in the "web" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best solution is store images and other private data in a private folder not accesible from public.
Then, you can implement a controller that get the request and read and render the image or other data.
In the controller you can implement the access control using the standar yii 'access' behavior.